# Vido Format/Codec for "2 Channel Video"

Tags: video, presentations

I am just watching Lecture videos and I was wondering: **Is there a video data format, that allows two different videos (synchronized) at the same Time?**

So for this example: One could be the lecturer and the other the presentation slides. With 2 channels in the Video, the viewer could decide which video he/she wants to view, or allow some free movable picture in picture mode.

Comment: i thought about that also but i don't know any codecs that do this. although it is definitively easy to implement.

Comment: i'm pretty sure [the matroska (mkv) format](https://www.matroska.org/technical/whatis/index.html) can put multiple video streams into the same file.  whether you can find player software that will play them back simultaneously is another question entirely.

Comment: Multi-channel videos with the features you mention are commonly found in Security Camera systems that allow digital export. They tend to be proprietary and awkward to work with in "normal" players because they are so different from the common assumptions we make regarding video playback. What you are asking for is an entire ecosystem: recording systems, codecs, containers, and playback systems that all exist today, but in very closed, very limited use formats.